# Do child processes copy entire arrays?

Tags: linux, unix, process, fork, pipe

I'm writing a basic UNIX program that involves processes sending messages to each other. My idea to synchronize the processes is to simply have an array of flags to indicate whether or not a process has reached a certain point in the code.

For example, I want all the processes to wait until they've all been created. I also want them to wait until they've all finished sending messages to each other before they begin reading their pipes.

I'm aware that a process performs a copy-on-write operation when it writes to a previously defined variable.

What I'm wondering is, if I make an array of flags, will the pointer to that array be copied, or will the entire array be copied (thus making my idea useless).

I'd also like any tips on inter-process communication and process synchronization.

***EDIT:*** The processes are writing to each other process' pipe. Each process will send the following information:

```
typedef struct MessageCDT{
    pid_t destination;
    pid_t source;
    int num;
} Message;
```

So, just the source of the message and some random number. Then each process will print out the message to stdout: Something along the lines of "process 20 received 5724244 from process 3".

Comment: Could you post more information about the processes? What are they doing? Why don't you use Threads? Why do you use an array of flags and not one controlling process, which controls all other processes?

Comment: @FranziskusKarsunke Sorry for lack of detail, I've updated the information. This is just a homework assignment. Multithreading is not what I'm working on. Could you elaborate a bit more on how a controlling process would work?

Comment: Well... If it's an assignment you should do it on your own^^

Comment: @FranziskusKarsunke I'm just trying to understand a concept and maybe a few tips. I'm not looking for actual code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unix processes have independent address spaces.  This means that the memory in one is totally separate from the memory in another.  When you call fork(), you get a new copy of the process.  Immediately on return from fork(), the only thing different between the two processes is fork()'s return value.  All of the data in the two processes are the same, but they are copies.  Updating memory in one cannot be known by the other, unless you take steps to share the memory.

There are many choices for interprocess communication (IPC) in Unix, including shared memory, semaphores, pipes (named and unnamed), sockets, message queues and signals.  If you Google these things you will find lots to read.

In your particular case, trying to make several processes wait until they all reach a certain point, I might use a semaphore or shared memory, depending on whether there is some master process that started them all or not.

If there is a master process that launches the others, then the master could setup the semaphore with a count equal to the number of processes to synchronize and then launch them.  Each child could then decrement the semaphore value and wait for the semaphore value to reach zero.

If there is no master process, then I might create a shared memory segment that contains a count of processes and a flag for each process.  But when you have two or more processes using shared memory, then you also need some kind of locking mechanism (probably a semaphore again) to ensure that two processes do not try to update the shared memory simultaneously.

Keep in mind that reading a pipe that nobody is writing to will block the reader until data appears.  I don't know what your processes do, but perhaps that is synchronization enough?  One other thing to consider if you have multiple processes writing to a given pipe, their data may become interleaved if the writes are larger than PIPE_BUF.  The value and location of this  macro are system dependent.

-Kevin

Comment: Just so you know, no modern *nix actually copies the whole address space.  They do a copy-on-write thing, arranging page table entries so that the two address spaces point to the same memory, and no copying is done until one or the other attempts to write to a given page.

Answer (score 2):

The entire array of flags will seem to be copied. It will not actually be copied until one process or another writes to it of course. But that's an implementation detail and transparent to the individual processes. As far as each process is concerned, they each get a copy of the array.

There are ways to make this not happen. You can use `mmap` with the `MAP_SHARED` option for the memory used for your flags. Then each sub-process will share the same region of memory. There's also Posix shared memory (which I, BTW, think is an awful hack). To find out about Posix shared memory, look at the [`shm_overview(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/shm_overview) man page.

But using memory in this way isn't really a good idea. On multi-core systems it's not always the case that when one process (or thread) writes to an area of shared memory that all other processes will see the value written right away. Frequently the value will hang out for awhile in the L2 cache and not be immediately flushed.

If you want to communicate using shared memory, you will have to used mutexes or the C++11 atomic operations to ensure that writes are properly seen by the other processes.

Comment: So if a process writes to one index of the array, the other processes won't see this change?

Comment: @seljuq70: No, they won't. No memory is shared between processes after a `fork` call unless you explicitly do something to make it happen.

Comment: Well, that answers that question. Shared memory it is, thanks for the help.

Comment: @seljuq70: Even with shared memory you will have to work to make sure processor caches stay appropriately synchronized. A shared array of flags will have odd results that you may not expect.